# No match, wildcard only covers a single DNS label

Tags: kubernetes, dns

Over [here](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/ingress/#hostname-wildcards), I couldn't understand why third example was a no match. If my wildcard is `*.foo.com` then why it can't match match Host header with value as "foo.com".

I tried to Google for "single DNS label" but really couldn't understand.

Comment: `*.example.com` (please don't use fake name for obfuscations) means something under `example.com` BUT NOT just `example.com`. Those are DNS rules that apply to every software; see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wildcard_DNS_record for details and explanations. Besides that, your question is offtopic here as not related to programming.

Comment: @PatrickMevzek Thanks for the link. BTW, I will actually use these hostname wildcards in my Kubernetes code file, so I can't agree that this can be categorized as "not related to programming".

Comment: Your question boils down to basically: why in DNS `*.example.com` does not match `example.com`. This is not a programming question. No matter where you have to use this wildcard record. The fact that you are in a Kubernetes case does not change anything to the core question, you would have the same one with any other software.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically, `*.foo.com` means you need to have `<something>.foo.com`. So, only `foo.com` is not matched. For simplicity you can think that wildcard `*` need to be replaced and cannot be omitted,  you have to have something in the place of `*` for matching this.

Comment: Ok thanks, and in place of "*" I cannot have two name like "bar.foo", right? If you can also explain why so then it will be helpful. Since my main question is answered so anyways accepting your answer.

Comment: yes you cannot have `bar.foo` in the place `*`, only one is allowed. Because, Wildcard matches require the HTTP host header is equal to the suffix of the wildcard rule and also wildcard only covers a single DNS label.